# In hiding price plugin add to cart not working

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have an extension of mage me which helps to hide the price for not logged in customers and shows for logged in customers.
But add to cart button is not showing in PDP page it is showing in listing page and other places but not in PDP page.

The extension I am using is https://mageme.com/magento-2-hide-price-extension-free.html (it is a free extension anyone can use).

The code required to block the price and add to cart is default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
        <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="hideprice/general/enable">
            <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">product_options_wrapper_bottom</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="hideprice/general/enable">
            <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">product_info_form_content</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="hideprice/general/enable">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string" />
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Any idea why add to cart is not coming only there.

Answer (score 1):

"To make layout changes available on every page, modify the default.xml file"
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

According to magento directives, applying a change to the default.xml all pages are modified according to what is written in them. If you need different behavior for a specific page you have to change the inherent layout.

I may not have learned the question unfounded, if so please be more specific.

###Edit from here###

go in default.xml and delete this lines

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info">
    <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="hideprice/general/enable">
        <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">product_info_form_content</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="hideprice/general/enable">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string" />
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

The code of this module has been wrongly written, removing these lines you can see the button inside the product sheet.
You should patch via ece-tool or composer by adjusting these lines instead of removing them.
I have removed the lines to perform a quick test, now it is up to you to find the best solution for your need

Cheers

Comment: actually add to cart is not coming only in PDP page I don't know whats the reason

Comment: check the answer I updated

Comment: If i remove this it will also show for guest users, i need it to show only for logged in users

Comment: the problem it's the module, it's not the right way to do what you need, because this block need to verify 2 selection:
- hideprice/general/enable
- hideprice/general/show-for-logged-users

But currently only one option are "checked"

Comment: check this https://github.com/dsasmita/magento2-hide-price-not-login

Comment: Thank you Riccardo for answering but now the issue has been fixed by the extension provider